# How to import a account from testnet?

Tags: ether, accounts, testnets

I recently traded BTC for 1 Ether using shapeshift.io

The transaction was successful, but there is no record of Ether in my local account.

[Here is the tx reference](https://www.etherchain.org/account/0x7b7E17Ed506fc0af0d472e093a56AF988a07611C).

I fear that I have made a mistake, transferring into a account on Testnet, instead of the main network - but can't find any literature on whether my hunch is true.

**More info:**

My Ethereum Wallet is the latest build (0.5.2), and all nodes / blocks are synced.

I'm not looking to build any apps for the moment, I'm merely interested in investing in the currency by holding Ether. If what I did was incorrect, what should I be doing instead?

If it makes any difference, the generated avatar displayed on the account is exactly the same as the one in my local account.

**tl;dr:** Purchased Ether using a account generated on testnet, but it's not reflecting locally. How to import an account from testnet?

Comment: So you sent your ether to 0x7b7E17Ed506fc0af0d472e093a56AF988a07611C?
If the avatar is the same as the one you see in mist, this should be the correct account. What address do you see displayed in Mist?

Comment: So I've managed to upload my wallet file to an online client side java version. It was able to tell me how many Ether was in the wallet, but still not reflecting on my account in my local Ethereum wallet.

I've read up about the differences between TestNet and the main network, but in my case (just wanting to hold Ether, the way one would hold BTC in a wallet) – what would be the best network to use?

Comment: Testnet ether does not really have any value, since you can receive it for free from the testnet faucet at https://zerogox.com/ethereum/wei_faucet. So if you want to invest in ether you should use the main net

Comment: Now I'm really confused.Somehow I've managed to purchase Ether on my testnet account, the one above.

Comment: Are you sure that you are on the testnet? I'm don't think shapeshift sells testnet ether. I would guess that you are on the live/public/main net and bought real ether.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to Ethereum data dir (on Linux `~/.ethereum`, on Windows somewhere in `AppData`).
2. Find folder `testnet/keystore`. It contains password encrypted private keys.
3. Find the private key file for you account with the name

   UTC--some-timestamp--7b7E17Ed506fc0af0d472e093a56AF988a07611C
4. Copy the file to your mainnet `keystore` folder (next to `testnet` folder).
5. The Ethereum Wallet should be updated automatically and show the new account.

Good luck.